# How do I specify a local location for a grails plugin with a dash in the name?

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

I have rebuilt the plugin grails-skin-loader and have it in the grails-skin-loader.zip file.

My BuildConfig.groovy has:

```
grails.plugin.location.skin-loader = "../interlated_git/interlated/grails-skin-loader"
grails.project.dependency.resolution = {
...
  plugins {
        compile ":skin-loader:1.0.9"
```

The error message I am getting seems to relate to the '-':

```
(grails.plugin.location.skin - loader) is a binary expression, but it should be a variable expression at line: 18 column: 36. File: grails-contact-form/grails-app/conf/BuildConfig.groovy @ line 18, column 36.
   grails.plugin.location.skin-loader = "../interlated_git/interlated/grails-skin-loader"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use quotes:

```
grails.plugin.location."skin-loader" = "../interlated_git/interlated/grails-skin-loader"
```

Comment: Ah - around last part - not the whole specification. Even in the documentation http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/plugins.html#creatingAndInstallingPlugins. Works.

Answer (score 1):

If the minus is in the first qualifier, you may use something like this (tested with Gradle script):

```
this."oss-releases.url"="https://something"
```